# Marlin keeps restarting when I push the LCD controller button

Tags: marlin, diy-3d-printer, reprap, arduino-mega-2650

I am new here and also new for the 3D printers world.  I have built a 3D printer myself. Everything seems okay, but, when I install Marlin firmware I can't use the printer.

While my printer is connected to my power supply (12 V; 30 A) and when I push the button on the screen for selecting the menu items, Marlin is restarting.

But, when I connect my computer with USB and power supply together, Its working fine

I am using RobotDyn Arduino Mega 2560, RobotDyn Graphic LCD controller, RobotDyn DRV8825

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! To be clear, you aren't pushing the reset button but pushing the rotating button?

Comment: Yes, I am pushing the rotating button for entering the menu.

Comment: Sorry, had to ask :-) Indeed a strange issue, I haven't seen that before!

Comment: Yes. Its strange. When I install repetier its work perfectly but with marlin I have this problem.

Comment: Normally the firmware beeps the speaker when you press buttons. Perhaps it's defective and shorts, drawing too much power and resetting the board.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE, that is what I was thinking as well. The description sounds like a short to me as well.

Answer (score 2):

If the trouble was just a short between 5 V and ground, the board probably would restart whenever you pushed the button, with all kind of power sources.

The fact that the Arduino restarts only when powered from RAMPS makes me wonder another cause for this problem.

It's well known that most of Arduino clones don't have a good voltage regulator onboard. This causes trouble when you power Arduino from RAMPS, because RAMPS sends 12 V to Arduino through Arduino's Vin pin, and this 12 V goes to Arduino's voltage regulator, which should reduce it to the 5 V used by ATMega MCU.

The question is, probably the Arduino's onboard voltage is running almost at its capacity and, when you press the button, the extra processing load or the redrawing of the display makes Arduino reset.

The solution would be disconnect diode D1 in RAMPS, and power Arduino from USB, or feeding 5V directly to Arduino's 5 V pin (not Vin).

A third option (more complex) would be feed about 7 V to Arduino barrel power-connector. This lower voltage would reduce the task of Arduino's onboard regulator. My 3D-printer uses an Arduino clone, but, as I discovered about this problem before building it, I've never powered it from RAMPS. I dessoldered D1 on RAMPS and, since the first day, Arduino was powered from USB, or from a DC-DC buck converter that reduces 12 V to 7.2 V.

Answer (score 0):

You are right! This thread help me solve a 1 year old problem. I had to buy a new LCD(different model) because I had the same problem. Every time I press down the controller button the system resets. Your clue about it having something to do with the speaker helped solve this mystery.

I had to comment out #define SPEAKER and it is now working.

This is a strange bug that only occurs with a the SKR-E3mini V2 and the most basic 12864 LCD AND Marlin 2.1.1. I have 2 printers so I can pretty much confirm in my case it only occurs in this particular configuration.